# Send mail fails because of SSL certificate, how to add new certificate or check if thats really the source error?

Tags: java, email, ssl, jboss, ssl-certificate

I'm new to ssl certificates and in our server (specs below 1.1) one month ago the "send mail" service stopped working. I followed the logs and it seems that there is a problem with a ssl certificate (Trace below 1.2)

- 1.1 Server specs: jdk 1.4.2, jboss ga 4.0.2 windows server 2003
- 1.2 Trace:

  ```
  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(DashoA12275)
      at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_az.a(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunJSSE_ax.a(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.j(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.a(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:183)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:201)
  at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440)
  ... 36 more
   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed
  at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:137)
  at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:202)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(DashoA12275)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DashoA12275)
  ... 48 more
      Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 Signature not available
  at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Security.java:672)
  at java.security.Security.getEngineClassName(Security.java:683)
  at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:1132)
  at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:169)
  at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:425)
  at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:383)
  at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:135)
  ... 51 more
  ```

What caught my attention was the "Signature not available" so I checked and read a lot but can't seem to find the root of this problem, no one has done any change to the server certificates or the java.security file, also the code that seems to get the error appears when I send a mail. the weird thing is that everything is working on my test server, but not in my production server.

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to run java1.4 which not supporting sha256 algorithm,

try http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

or move to newer jdk 1.5/6 will do

Comment: ill give it a go to bouncycastle, upgrading to a new jdk its not an option. but is there an explanation why last month it worked like a charm (for more than 2 years) and now it just doesnt work?